# Modify & replace tag content in place using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have this string

`String source = "<code> <b>code1</b></code><code><i>code2</i></code>";`

I want this output

`String source = "<code> <b>code123</b></code><code><i>code256</i></code>";`

I am able to get all text inside `code`

```
Elements code = doc.select("code");

for (Element c : code) {
    System.out.println(c.text());
}
```

but not able to modify the text in place. How can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
myElement.text("my text here");
```

In your case:

```
Elements code = doc.select("code");
for(Element c:code) {

    //will print the text which the Element currently has
    System.out.println(c.text());

    //will set the text
    c.text("<b>code123</b><i>code256</i>");
}
```

As you can see, the `text()` method works to get the text, but *also* to set the text.